# JavaFX TableView Pagination - not updating TableView on updating ObservableList data

Tags: javafx

I have a `TableView` with `Pagination`.  Like this (simplified):

```
public void createPagination() {
    Pagination pagination = new Pagination((allDataCount / rowsPerPage) + 1, 0);
    pagination.setPageFactory(this::createPage);
}

private Node createPage(int pageIndex) {
    int fromIndex = pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
    int toIndex = Math.min(fromIndex + rowsPerPage, allDataCount);
    table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));

    return new BorderPane(table);
}
```

The problem is, when I make an update to the `data` (`ObservableList`). The change is not visible in the `TableView`.

As I see it, the problem is in `data.subList`. If I set items with `table.setItems(data)`, all the changes are visible immediately in the `TableView`.

Any ideas, how could I solve this?

**EDIT**

I'm updating data like this:

```
//prepare new/changed Test object
Test test = new Test();
test.setId(1000);

int selectedIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() + pageIndex * rowsPerPage;
data.set(selectedIndex, test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FXCollections.observableArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-java.util.Collection-) "Creates a new observable list with the items added to it" - i.e. it is an observable list that is initialized with the data you pass in. Hence, changes to the original list won't be reflected in the new list it creates.

You need [`FXCollections.observableList(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-), which "Constructs an ObservableList backed by the original list" - i.e. changes to the underlying list will be reflected in the new list, and vice-versa.

So you want

```
table.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(data.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)));
```

Now the list displayed by the table is just a view of a portion of the overall `data` list. So changes to `table.getItems()` will be visible to `data`, and vice-versa. However, the table view is only observing `table.getItems()`, and even though `data` is an observable list, notification of changes to `data` will not be passed to `table.getItems()`. Because of this, you need to make changes to the list the table is observing:

```
int selectedIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() ;
table.getItems().set(selectedIndex, test);
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but this still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you update the question to show how you are making updates to the data?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. And a BIG thank you! That solved my problem.